# Strange behavior of float point

Tags: java, floating-point

I understand random.Float() bring back a float number between 0.0 to 0.999...

but for an unknown reason, almost the same code brings back 2 different answers.

I want to understand why t1 could random 1.0 and t2 can not.

I tried to check for a similar question but could not find out anything similar

```
    Random rand = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++) {
        float t1 = 0.9f + rand.nextFloat() * 0.1f;
        float t2 = 0.1f + rand.nextFloat() * 0.9f;
        if (t1 == 1.0f) {
            System.out.println("t1 " + t1);
        }
        if (t2 == 1.0f) {
            System.out.println("t2 " + t2);
        }
    }
```

no error messages I just can not understand why t1 bring back sometimes 1.0 number and t2 does not.

**Edit:
 t1 generate maxmium of 0.999... *0.1 which is 0.0999... + 0.9 = 0.9999...
t2 generate maxmimum of 0.999... *0.9 which is 0.8999... + 0.1 = 0.9999...
Both should be the same no?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The primary cause of the difference is that .9 + *x* •.1 is larger than .1 + *x* • .9 for any *x* < 1, and `Random.nextFloat` returns values less than 1. For the largest value it returns, the former expression is so close to 1 that rounding it to `float` produces 1, but the latter expression is farther from 1, and rounding it to `float` produces the next `float` below 1.

[The largest value that `Random.nextFloat` returns is `Random.nextfloat` 16777215/16777216.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextFloat()) Let *M* be this maximum, and let *d* = 1 − *M* = 1/16777216.

If we calculated `t1` using real numbers, its maximum value would be .9 + *M*•.1. = .9 + (1−*d*)•.1 = 1−.1•*d*. Similarly, `t2` would be .1 + *M*•.9 = .1 + (1-*d*)•.9 = 1-.9•*d*.

Now we can easily see that the maximum of `t1` (if calculated with real numbers) is .1•*d* away from 1, but `t2` is .9•*d* away from 1.

A reason the largest value `Random.nextFloat` returns is 16777215/16777216 is that it is the largest `float` less than 1. The precision of the `float` format is such that the steps between representable values leading up to 1 are 1/16777216. This means that the two representable values in this neighborhood are 16777215/16777216 and 1, and *d* is the distance between them. Our calculations above show us the maximum value of `t1` is just .1•*d* away from 1. So, when it is rounded to `float`, 1 is the nearest `float`.

In contrast, the maximum value of `t2` is .9•*d* away from 1. This means it is just .1•*d* away from 16777215/16777216. So, when it is rounded to `float`, 16777215/16777216 is the nearest `float`.

That is using real-number arithmetic. Below, I will show the floating-point arithmetic. It has rounding errors, but these turn out to be small enough not to change the results.

In `Java`, the source texts `.1f` and `.9f` are converted to `float`, which yield 0.100000001490116119384765625 and 0.89999997615814208984375. The arithmetic in the expressions is performed using `double`, and then the result is rounded to `float` for assignment to `t1` or `t2`.

The largest that `t1` can be may be calculated:

- Substituting the largest return value of `nextFloat` yields `0.9f + 16777215./16777216 * 0.1f;`.
- Evaluating in `double` arithmetic yields 0.999999971687793642871611154987476766109466552734375.
- Converting to `float` yields 1, because that `double` value is between 0.999999940395355224609375 (the next lower `float` value) and 1 (the next higher), and it is closer to the latter than to the former.

The largest that `t2` can be may be calculated:

- Substituting the largest return value of `nextFloat` yields `0.1f + 16777215./16777216 * 0.9f;`.
- Evaluating in `double` arithmetic yields 0.99999992400407933246242464520037174224853515625.
- Converting to `float` yields 0.999999940395355224609375.